# Close primefaces dialog from iFrame

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've a page on which I want to show a dialog.

Code :

page1.xhtml

```
<p:commandLink value="Show Dialog" oncomplete="dlgWVar.show();"/>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlgWVar"
          width="800"
          id="dialog"
          position="top"
          modal="true"
          header="Test Dialog"
          height="500">

    <iframe src="page2.xhtml" width="100%" height="500px" style="border-width: 0PX;">
    </iframe>

</p:dialog>
```

Now on this dialog I've iFrame in which the page2.xhtml is linked.

page2.xhtml

```
   <p:commandButton value ="Close Dialog">
   </p:commandButton>
```

page2.xhtml contains a commandButton. Now I've to close the dialog after clicking the commandButton.

Don't know how to do that.
What should I write in commandButton on page2.xhtml so that the dialog on page1.xhtml will be closed. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: This is very bad design. You should use server side includes/templating via Facelets instead of HTML iframe.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the suggestion. I'm going to improve my design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For older PrimeFaces version try with `window.parent.dlgWVar.hide()`. This is only possible if both main window and iframe show the page from the same domain.

For PrimeFaces version of 5 and up, see the other answer

Answer (score 0):

For me

```js
window.parent.PF('dlgWVar').hide()
```

worked.